# Displaying value on KineticJs Text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I want to change the text in my container for kinetic js using keyup event in jquery but it doesn't display. I tried getting the value then display it on a span element and it works fine.
Here's my code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'canvasContainer',
        width: 800,
        height: 800
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var message = '';

    $(function(){
        $('#txtArea').change(function(){
            message = $(this).val();
            $('.output').text(message);

            var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
                x: 0,
                y: 10,
                text: message,
                fontSize: 30,
                fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                fill: 'blue'
            });
            layer.add(simpleText);
        }).keyup(function(){
            $(this).change();
        });
    });
    stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add or change a Kinetic object, be sure you call layer.draw() to cause the drawing to be visible.

BTW, instead of adding a new simpleText with each change, you might want to just change the text in the existing text object

```
// declare simpleText before .change()

var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 0,
    y: 10,
    text: "",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    fill: 'blue'
});
layer.add(simpleText);

// then inside .change()

simpleText.setText(message);
layer.draw();
```